# relation between eigenspace and Galois group

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, galois-theory

How, the eigenspace of $\varphi^r$, is stable under the action of the Galois group generated by $\varphi ^r$?

$\varphi$ is the frobenius endomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (assuming that the eigenvalue is in the fixed field of $\varphi$): $\varphi$ and $\varphi^r$ commute.

> So if $\varphi^r(x)=\lambda x$ then $\varphi^r(\varphi(x))=\varphi(\varphi^r(x)).$

Comment: Dear Jyrki, Thank you , can you please give me a hint for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325581/elliptic-curve-isogenies-frobenius-endomorphism-relation-to-characteristic-equa